# What parameters are available for Firebase Cloud Messaging?

Tags: google-chrome, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps

Is it possible to use other parameters than *title, body, icon, click_action* for [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging)?
(I need to add a YES and NO button along with a seperate click_action to PHP/cURL file.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are other options.  Please look at [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support) to see the spec for the notification payload.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#notification-payload-support

Notification type messages don't offer you a whole lot of ability to take control of the notification behavior.  If you need to customize things, you will probably need to use a data type message and write code to deal with the payload you choose to send.

Comment: Will the Android FCM payload options work for a Progressive Web App (PWA) that gets installed on an Android (7) device via Chrome for Android browser?

Comment: I don't know.  That sounds like a different question you could ask.